# why do i get "attempt to call global 'require' (a nil value)"?

Tags: lua

I have 3 lua files, Init.lua, FreeCamera.lua and Camera.lua ,

init.lua calls require "Core.Camera.FreeCamera"

Free Camera:

```
module(...)
require "Core.Camera.Camera"

local M = {}
FreeCamera = M

M = Class( Camera )
function M:__constructor(x,y,z)
  self.Active = false
  self.x = x
  self.y = y
  self.z = z
end
```

and

```
module(...)

local M = {}
Camera = M

M = Class()

function M:__constructor(x,y,z)
  self.Active = false
  self.x = x
  self.y = y
  self.z = z
end
```

FreeCamera "inherits" Camera kind of. I am trying to require FreeCamera in my init file and I am getting this:

..\Content\Modules\Core\Camera\FreeCamera.lua:12: attempt to call global 'require' (a nil value). Any idea Why? Am I using require the right way?
Clearly it is getting into FreeCamera.lua, which is great, but it gets stuck on the next require.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To 'import' identifiers into a module, you might write code something like the following:

```
local require = require
local Class = Class
local io, table, string
    = io, table, string
local type, pairs, ipairs, assert
    = type, pairs, ipairs, assert

module(...)

local Camera = require 'Core.Camera.Camera'
```

and so on.

The `module(...)` command removes (almost) everything from your global-variable namespace—it creates a new global namespace that belongs to the new module.  Aside from a couple of special identifiers like `_M` and `_G`, the new namespace is empty.   But `local` identifiers stay visible.

The `local` declarations make the dependencies of your module clear, and they can also communicate your intent.  As a bonus, they make access to the named identifiers more efficient.  So this is very good Lua style.

Comment: perfect! i noticed this in the critique page on the module function, I am glad to know that it is good style!!

Answer (score 7):

The `module` function creates a new empty environment and so `require` is not found when called. Try calling `require` before calling `module`.

Comment: That seems to have done the trick, now it says Class() is nil, but if i change that from a global, to require, it should work according to what you are saying.

Answer (score 0):

You can:

`lua
module(..., package.seeall)`

To import the global environment into your module. This is (presumably) the easiest solution, but may not be to your taste.

Comment: This is the expedient solution, but it introduces a bunch of other issues due to inclusion of the global environment inside the module's environment. The current best practice is to avoid the `module()` function and use `local` generously. Notice that in Lua 5.2, the function `module()` is deprecated, for example.